# Deleting row in numpy array based on condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array of shape [6,2] and I want to remove the subarrays with the third element containing 0.

```
array([[0, 2, 1], #Input
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [2, 1, 2]])

array([[0, 2, 1], #Output
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [2, 1, 2]])
```

My code is `positives = gt_boxes[np.where(gt_boxes[range(gt_boxes.shape[0]),2] != 0)]`

It works but is there a simplified method to this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use *boolean indexing*.

```
In [413]: x[x[:, -1] != 0]
Out[413]: 
array([[0, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [2, 1, 2]])
```

---

1. `x[:, -1]` will retrieve the last column
2. `x[:, -1] != 0` returns a boolean mask
3. Use the mask to index into the original array

Comment: Dang it. I didn't get to finish writing my solution, and it was _still_ longer than this anyways. +1

Comment: @ChristianDean Yo that's how I feel 99% of the time in this tag :p